# Nmap multiple os information

Tags: nmap

Pardon in advance if this is a very noob question..
So I am learning to use `nmap` command and currently, I am doing a scan to check for the OS details of an image.

The command I have used is `nmap -O -sV <ip address>` and I am slightly confused by the OS details it outputted as I am trying to derive the exact OS version, to check if there are any vulnerability in the version.

It is as follows:

```
Running: Linux 3.X|4.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:4
OS details: Linux 3.2 - 4.9
```

While I am unable to access/ log into the said image, based off the above result, can I presume that there are 2 different Linux OS versions, in this case, one is running on Linux 3.2 and the other is on Linux 4.9?

Is it possible that an image can have multiple OS (as seen above, assuming what I mentioned above is correct)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is answered here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121964/nmap-shows-multiple-outputs-in-os-detection

Answer (score 1):

Nmap does not always know the exact OS on the host you are scanning, so it tries to geuss it.

Comment: Ah, in that case, my conjecture is wrong then. But rather the above output I have posted is telling me that it could be a Linux version 3.X.Y or 4.X.Y  then and not 2 OS? Am I right to presume so?

Comment: I can not tell you for 100% but that is also the way I understand it.
I think it will be more helpfull to you to ask your question on this site: https://security.stackexchange.com/